# Chromium extesions are broken

Tags: 11.10, chromium

After upgrade ubuntu to 11.10 chormium doesn't display extensions icons and extensions don't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give us some more details? What version of Chromium? (Wrench icon > About Chromium)

Comment: tried reinstalling chromium?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).